# literal_eval of tuple with a single element

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I am using `ast.literal_eval(str)` to evaluate a string containing a tuple such as `('a', 'b', 'c')`. However, if for some reason this tuple only contains a single element, the expression ignores the parenthesis and returns only the element:

```
>>> string = "('a')"
>>> x = ast.literal_eval(string)
>>> x
'a'
```

Is there a non-hackish way to solve this? This problem is exacerbated by the fact that sometimes, I might have a tuple of tuples, like `(('a','b'))` and as such cannot just check for type. Thanks!

Comment: `(x)` is not a 1-tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `('a')` is not a tuple but a string treated as `a`. Tuple with only one object is defined as `('a',)` (note the `,`)

```
>>> type('a')
<type 'str'>    <-- String
>>> type(('a'))
<type 'str'>    <-- String
>>> type(('a',))
<type 'tuple'>  <-- Tuple
```

Comment: Right. But my goal is to avoid that little comma completely; is there a way to do that?

Comment: If you'll remove that, it won't be a tuple. It is a syntax of Python :)

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks, however!